# Where to store/access my Java re-usable classes for NetBeans

Tags: java, class-library

In the process of porting some of my generic class libraries from C++ to Java. Is there a place I can store my class files such that they will be visible by the class browser in NetBeans for any new projects that I create? Not really understanding the Java class library structure (like MSVC's "lib" and "include" folders that are global to all projects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is your project that contains your utilities you should create separate project. Let's call it `Utilities`. Now when you create other project (let's call it MyApp) make it dependent on the Utilities project. Your IDE will do what it is required.

Actually from java point of view you just have to add all required classes to classpth. When you are running compiler (javac) or JVM (java) you can pass argument `-classpath` and then list of your libraries (either jar files or root directories where your class files are stored). The list is colon separated in Unix and semicolon separated in Windows.

Java also supports alias of parameter `-classpath` that is  `-cp`

For example the following command line will run your application that depends on `mylib.jar`.

`java -cp mylib.jar;myapp.jar com.mycompany.Main`

I'd recommend you also to take a look on Maven: the build tool that helps you to manage your dependencies for non-trivial projects and de facto the standard in java world.